# Display not showing properly in a single row

Tags: html, css

Currently I have a container where I have my content which stores name and designation in 1 column and an image in the next. I want my content to look like this where the content is to the left and the linked in image floats to the right:

[image]

But currently my content looks like this where its stacking the image below my name and desig:

[image]

Here is my html code:

```
<div class="container5">
            <div class="overlay">
            <div stlye={{display:"flex", flexDirection:"row"}}>
            <div stlye={{flexDirection:"column"}}>
              <p style={{color:"white", paddingTop:"15px", paddingLeft:"10px"}}>Random Name</p>
              <p style={{fontSize:"14px", color:"yellow", paddingLeft:"10px"}}>Software Engineer</p>
              </div>
              <div style={{float:"right"}}>
                <img style={{height:"20px", width:"20px", backgroundColor:"white"}} src="linkedin.svg"/>
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>
 </div>
```

And my CSS:

```
.container5 {
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: coral;
}

.overlay {
  clip-path: polygon(0 36%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 1rem;
  bottom: -100%;
  background-color: #0e2043;
  transition: bottom 250ms ease;
}
```

Comment: does stlye look right?

Comment: Oh sorry about that didn't notice that, my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use bootstrap to Achieve that

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9">
              <p style={{color:"white", paddingTop:"15px", paddingLeft:"10px"}}>Random Name</p>
              <p style={{fontSize:"14px", color:"yellow", paddingLeft:"10px"}}>Software Engineer</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <img style={{height:"20px", width:"20px", backgroundColor:"white",float:"right"}} src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

See more about bootstrap in w3schools https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/

Answer (score 0):

I would use CSS grid to arrange your items. Its a clean way to position all your elements by defining a grid with columns and rows. You can define the size of each entry in your grid, the gap between them and you can extent its usability with flexbox

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout